# Why does the soap client cut off the subelements?

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

I'm using the PHP SoapClient for making a request. The XML structure should look like this:

```xml
<tar:setPackage>
    <tar:Package>
        <tar:Content>
            <tar:Object xsi:type="par:Car">
                <par:Descritpion>1</par:Descritpion>
                <par:Color>Blue</par:Color>
            </tar:Object>
        </tar:Content>
        <pev:Supplier>
            <pev:Id>04</pev:Id>
        </pev:Supplier>
    </tar:Package>
</tar:setPackage>
```

But unfortunately, the result of the output of `__getLastRequest()` looks like this:

```xml
<tar:setPackage>
    <tar:Package>
        <tar:Content>
            <tar:Object xsi:type="par:Car"/>
        </tar:Content>
        <pev:Supplier>
            <pev:Id>04</pev:Id>
        </pev:Supplier>
    </tar:Package>
</tar:setPackage>
```

As you can see here, the subelements have been cut off.
It must be related to the xsi-type "par: Car" because if it is changed, the sub-elements will not be truncated.

According to the referenced WSDL file, 'Car' derives from 'Object'.

Here's how I use the PHP Soap Client:

```php
$parm = array();
$parm2 = array();
$parm2[] = new SoapVar("1", XSD_STRING, null, null, "Description", "http://dummy-url.com/car");
$parm[] = new SoapVar($parm2, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "Car", "http://dummy-url.com/car", "Object", "http://dummy-url.com/objectdata");
$response = $client->setPackage(new SoapVar($parm, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
print_r($client->__getLastRequest());
```

How can I prevent the truncation of subelements?

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?